# Do you need locking with only reading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wanted to know that is it safe to assume that if multiple threads are accessing a single static container (boost::unordered_map) there is no need for locking the access to the container if multiple threads are only reading data from it. and no writing is done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When multiple threads are only reading and performing no write operation, you do not need to synchronize access.

Paragraph 1.10 of the C++11 Standard defines conflicting operations with respect to data races as:

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one
>   accesses or modifies the same memory location.

And then of course, per 1.10/21:

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads,
>   at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. [...]

Comment: To be extra, extra safe you might want to do a barrier operation after initializing the static container.

Comment: Also make sure that the "read" does not change internal state of the container (while unordered_map and most others most likely do not do this a specialized container might modify an internal cache or the ordering of elements to optimize lookup of frequently used items)

Comment: @josefx: If it does, I expect that to be synchronized by the container itself. Since C++11, `const` operations on library objects and objects used with standard library types must be thread-safe (see [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank)). Since `boost::unordered_map` inspired `std::unorderded_map`, I would be very surprised if that was not the case